# Error analysis / propagation : trigonometry

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

If the hypotenuse of a triangle is (1536 +- 3)m long, and the (non right-angle) angle measured from the ground is (22.2 +-0.1) degrees, what is the height of the triangle, and the error in this?

sin(theta) = opp/hypotenuse = h/x

h = x sin(theta)

dh = ?

Comment: Did you try googling error propagation rules? [First result](https://www.lhup.edu/~dsimanek/scenario/errorman/rules.htm) has the answer....

Answer (score 1):

Assume the values are normally distributed without correlation (i.e. $\Delta(x+y) = \sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}$), then

\begin{align}
\Delta h 
&= \Delta ( x \sin \theta ) \\
&= \sqrt{ (\Delta x \cdot \sin \theta)^2 + (x \cdot \Delta (\sin \theta))^2 } \tag{product rule} \\
&= \sqrt{ (\Delta x \cdot \sin \theta)^2 + (x\cos \theta \cdot \Delta \theta)^2 }. \tag{$\tfrac d{d\phi}\sin \phi = \cos \phi$}
\end{align}